# The term 'docker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet AWS buildspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

docker : The term 'docker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Docker command in buildspec.yml failed to execute.
**Command**: 
- docker build -f .\WebServices\WebServices\Dockerfile -t kwebservices .
- docker tag kwebservices:dev 915700481289.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/kwebservices:dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further information it's harder to give the steps you need to fix this- but the problem is that docker is not installed (or PATH configured in a way that makes it globally available) on your build image.